# Prove Lyapunov condition for iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Show that if $X_1, X_2,\cdots X_n$ are i.i.d with $E[|X_1|^3]< \infty$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_n^{3}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} E[|X_i|^3]= 0$

**My attempt:** Since $X_1, X_2,\cdots X_n$ are i.i.d, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} E[|X_i|^3] = nE(|X_n|^3)$. Now, by Lyapunov's inequality, $\infty > E(|X_n|^3)\geq [E(|X_n|^2)]^{\frac{3}{2}}\geq (\sigma_{n}^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} = \sigma_{n}^{3}$. But this means $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_n^{3}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} E[|X_i|^3] = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{nE(|X_n|^3)}{\sigma_{n}^{3}}\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n = \infty$ (?!)

**My question:** What is wrong with the proof above though? Or is the problem statement wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was found in the inequality
$$ E|X_n|^2 \geq \sigma_n^2 $$
Where you probably messed up $\sigma_n^2$ as the variance of the sum with $\sigma_i^2$ the variance of $X_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment and what you have done, it is simple to see that $s_n^3=(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2)^{3/2}=n^{3/2}\sigma^3$ (as $X_n$ are iid) and this gives $\dfrac{nE|X_1|^3}{n^{3/2}\sigma^3}=C\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2}}\to0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please help check my proof for this more difficult one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994012/show-a-logarithmic-sequence-converging-almost-surely-and-compute-its-limit