# Proving $\frac{\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)}{\sqrt{u_2-\sigma^4}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_l, X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d. with $E(X_1 ) = u$, $\operatorname{Var } (X_1) = \sigma^2$ and  $u_2 = E[(X_1 - u)^4]$. Let $S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2$ where $\bar{X}_n = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{n} X_i}{n}$. Prove that $\frac{\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)}{\sqrt{u_2-\sigma^4}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution sense.

**My thought:** I tried to prove this using Levy-Cramer theorem with the help of Taylor series expansion, but I could not find the characteristic function of the given messy expression. Could someone please help find $\phi_{\frac{\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)}{\sqrt{u_2-\sigma^4}}} (t)$ in terms of $\phi_{X} (h(t))$ where $h(t)$ could be any functions as long as the transformation makes sense? Otherwise, any inputs would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assume that $u = 0$ without loss of generality. You can do this because $S_n^2$ doesn't change if you consider $X_i-u$ instead of $X_i$.

We are going to need the [multivariate central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT) here. It is the same as the ordinary central limit theorem but instead of variance you have the covariance matrix of the random vector. Note that the sequence $\left(\begin{pmatrix}X_i\\ X_i^2\end{pmatrix}\right)_i$ is i.i.d and it does have a covariance matrix since the fourth moment of $X_1$ exists as stated in your question. So let's apply the central limit theorem to this sequence.

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}0\\ \sigma^2 \end{pmatrix}\right) \rightsquigarrow N(0,\Sigma)$$
Here $\Sigma$ denotes the covariance matrix of  $\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\ X_1^2\end{pmatrix}$.

Next we are going to use the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). Note that $S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - \bar{X}_n^2$. So then (using the notation on the Wikipedia page) the transformation we have is $g(x,y) = y - x^2$. Make sure you check the conditions needed on $g$ for the delta method to work.

So then,
$$\sqrt{n}\left(S_n^2-\sigma^2\right) \rightsquigarrow N(0,\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\Sigma\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix})$$

By construction $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\Sigma\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = Var(X_1^2)$. Check that $Var(X_1^2) = u_2 - \sigma^4$.

Hence

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{u_2 - \sigma^4}}\sqrt{n}\left(S_n^2-\sigma^2\right) \rightsquigarrow N(0,1)$$

Answer (score 2):

We can replace $X_n$ by $X_n-u$, hence we can assume that $u=0$. We haved 
\begin{align}
 \sqrt n\left( S_n^2-\sigma^2\right)&=\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i^2 -\sigma^2\right) -2 \sqrt n\overline{X_n}^2 +  \sqrt n\overline{X_n}^2\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i^2 -\sigma^2\right) - \sqrt n\overline{X_n}^2.
\end{align}
Now, notice that $$\tag{*}   \sqrt n\overline{X_n}^2 =\frac 1{\sqrt n}\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}  \sum_{i=1}^nX_i   \right)^2, $$
hence by Slutsky's lemma and the central limit theorem, $\sqrt n\overline{X_n}^2\to 0$ in probability.

In order to reach the wanted conclusion, use the central limit theorem for the i.i.d. centered sequence $\left(\left(X_i^2-\sigma^2\right)/\sqrt{ u_2-\sigma^2} \right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ (because the variance of $X_1^2-\sigma^2$ is $\mathbb E\left[X_1^4\right]-\sigma^4=u_2-\sigma^4$).

Comment: thank you very much for your help. So, for the last step, how do we get $Var(X_i^2)$, since it equals to $Var(X_i^2-\sigma^2)$? I tried rewriting the sum as $\sqrt{n}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i^2-\sigma^2)}{n} - u^2)  + u^2\sqrt{n}$, and by using the CLT for our sequence $(X_i^2-\sigma^2)_{i\geq 1}$, the first term goes to $N(0,1)$, but the 2nd term blows up:P I am not sure how would you rewrite this to avoid this blow-up term?

Comment: We have $\mathrm{Var}(X_1^2)=E( (X_1^2)^2-(\sigma^2)^2=EX_1^4 -\sigma^4$. The second term is computed in (*). Did you verify the expression?

Comment: yes, I did. But then again, we don't have $E(X_1^4)$, so I could not see what you meant by "renormalization to get a variance equal to $1$" except the way I shown in my comment above? Did you meant dividing both side by $\sqrt{u_2-\sigma^4}$?

Comment: What do you meant by "we don't have $E[X_1^4]$? I have edited this part.

Comment: my apology for my dumb question. The reason is I forgot  your proof used $u=0$. This implies $E(X_i^2) = \sigma^2$, which makes $E(X_i^2 - \sigma^2) = 0$, so we could rewrite your last expression as  $\sqrt{n}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i^2 - \sigma^2)}{n\sqrt{u_2-\sigma^2}})$, and this is indeed CLT.

Comment: could you please help review my proof for the almost surely convergence part in the following problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994012/show-a-logarithmic-sequence-converging-almost-surely-and-compute-its-limit