# Show $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_j^2}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Prove that $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_j^2}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$$ in distribution.

**My attempt:** I was trying to modify the following result, but not successful at all:

*"Given the same condition on $A_1, A_2,\ldots$, let $Y_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_jA_j$ where $\left\{b_j\right\}$ is a sequence of constant. If $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\max_{j\leq n} b_j^2}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j^2} = 0$$ then $\dfrac{Y_n}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j^2}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution."*

So I could let $b_j = \frac{1}{N}$, and dividing both the numerator and denominator of our fraction by $N$ to obtain $Y_n$ in the numerator, but the denominator is still a variable, so I could not do anything here.

Could anyone please help give some thoughts on this problem? It's quite difficult due to the ugly denominator. I'm seriously stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: You can use Slutsky's lemma to immediately finish the proof. If you are not allowed to use it directly, then just look at its proof.

Comment: Simple consequence of the convergences $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow N(0,1)\qquad\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_j^2\rightarrow1$$ in distribution and almost surely, respectively.

Comment: @Did: Thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nA_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2}}$$

By the central limit theorem $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i \rightsquigarrow N(0,1)$. By the strong law of large numbers applied to the sequence $(A_i^2)_i$, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2 \to E[A_1^2] = 1$ almost surely and hence in probability. By the continuous mapping theorem, $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2} \to \sqrt{1} = 1$ almost surely and hence in probability. By Slutsky's lemma,

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^2}} \rightsquigarrow N(0,1)$$

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a ton yor your help.

Comment: @user177196 You are welcome.

Comment: could you give this problem a try as well? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994221/proving-frac-sqrtns-n2-sigma2-sqrtu-2-sigma4-rightarrow-n0-1