# A transformation $g$ such that $g(S^2)$ has asymptotic distribution depending on $\beta_2$ only

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. RVs with $E|X_1|^4 < \infty$. Let $\operatorname{var}(X_1) = \sigma^2$, $\beta_2 = \mu_4/\sigma^4$.
>
> (a) Using CLT for i.i.d. RVs, show that $\sqrt{n}(S^2-\sigma^2)\stackrel{L}\rightarrow N(0, \mu_4-\sigma^4)$.
>
> (b) Find a transformation $g$ such that $g(S^2)$ has asymptotic distribution that depends on $\beta_2$ alone, not on $\sigma^2$.

I have completed part (a). But got stuck on finding $g$. I know I have to use the theorem:

> $Y_n$ is $AN(\mu, \sigma^2_n)$, with $\sigma^2_n\rightarrow 0$ and $\mu$ fixed real. $g$ be differentiable at $\mu$ with $g'(\mu)\neq 0$, then $g(Y_n)$ is $AN(g(\mu), [g'(\mu)]^2\sigma^2_n)$

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

($AN(\cdot)$ means asymptotically normal distribution.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994221/proving-frac-sqrtns-n2-sigma2-sqrtu-2-sigma4-rightarrow-n0-1?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a variance stabilising transformation on $S^2$.

Let $\sigma_T^2=\mu_4-\sigma^4$, so that $\sigma_T^2=\beta_2\sigma^4-\sigma^4=\sigma^4(\beta_2-1)$.

By delta method, for a function $g$ that is differentiable at $\sigma^2$ with $g'(\sigma^2)\ne 0$, we have

$$\sqrt{n}\left(g(S^2)-g(\sigma^2)\right)\stackrel{a}\sim N\left(0,\sigma_T^2([g'(\sigma^2)]^2\right)\tag{*}$$

Set $\sigma_T\,g'(\sigma^2)=c$, a non-zero constant.

Therefore,

$$\sigma^2\sqrt{\beta_2-1}\,g'(\sigma^2)=c \implies \int g'(\sigma^2)\,d\sigma^2=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\beta_2-1}}\int \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\,d\sigma^2$$

Choosing $c=1/2$ (and ignoring constant of integration), you get

$$\color{blue}{g(\sigma^2)=\frac{\ln\sigma}{\sqrt{\beta_2-1}}}$$

So $(*)$ gives

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\beta_2-1}}(\ln S-\ln \sigma)\stackrel{a}\sim N\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

That is,

$$\sqrt{n}(\ln S-\ln \sigma)\stackrel{a}\sim N\left(0,\frac{1}{4}(\beta_2-1)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the asymptotic distribution in (a) gives:

$$\frac{S_n^2}{\sigma^2} \overset{\text{Asymp}}{\sim} \text{N} \Big( 1, \frac{\beta_2-1}{n} \Big).$$

So, taking the parameter $\beta_2$ as fixed, this gives you an asymptotically pivotal quantity (where the distribution does not depend on $\sigma^2$ but that parameter appears in the quantity).  If you are allowed to use the true variance parameter in your function $g$ then you are done, but if not, then it is unlikely there is a solution.  Because it gives the scale of the sample variance, the only way you will be able to remove the variance parameter from this quantity (without having the function degenerate down to a form whose distribution no longer depends on $\beta_2$) is if you replace the variance parameter with an alternative estimator of the variance.

Comment: Is it correct to write the asymptotic distribution depending on $n$? I understand it is just a rearrangement, but the asymptotic distribution is obtained when $n\to \infty$, so I don't think we can write "$\ldots\overset{\text{Asymp}}{\sim} \text{N} \Big( 1, \frac{\beta_2-1}{n} \Big)$".

Comment: This is a shorthand notation, so it holds only by specifying its underlying strict meaning (similar to a limit statement).  The strict meaning would not involve a limiting distribution that depends on $n$.  In the present case I have not elaborated on the strict meaning since the only goal is to find the function $g$.  The shorthand statement holds so long as you interpret it as an appropriate limiting statement.'