# Convergence Rate of Sample Variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Question: Given $X_1,X_2,...$ as an sequence of iid distributed random variables with $E(X_i)=0 $ and $V(X_i)=σ^2$ and the fourth order moment $E(X_i^4)<\infty$. Show that:
$\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,E[(X_i^2-\sigma^2)^2])$, where $S_n^2$ is the sample variance.

I am sure that we have to employ the fact that $S^2_n\xrightarrow{p} \sigma^2$ together with the Central Limit Theorem. But I still can not figure out the exact proof of this problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1994221/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512340/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3426249/321264.

Answer (score 1):

$S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac{n}{n-1}\bar{X}_n^2$.
The second term converges to $0$ almost surely and can be ignored. Apply the central limit theorem to the first term.

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer is correct. But there is still one missing part for me to complete the proof: while separating out the second term, we have to show that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}^2)\xrightarrow{p}0$, but I get stuck again, could you please help me out?

Comment: @MathFinanceLearner The strong law of large numbers implies $\bar{X}_n \to E[X_1]=0$ almost surely, so $\frac{n}{n-1} \bar{X}_n^2 \to 0$ almost surely as well.

Comment: I see thank you so much!