# Asymptotic distribution of sample variance

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with $E(X_i)=\mu$ and $Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Find the asymptotic distribution of $S_n^2$.
>
> Hint: Use $$ S_n^2=\frac{n}{n-1}\left\{ \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2-(\bar{X}_n-\mu)^2\right\}.$$

My attempt:

- Note that $E[(X_i-\mu)^2] = E(X_i^2)-2\mu E(X_i) + \mu^2 = \sigma^2$. Thus, applying the CLT, we find that $\sqrt{n}\{ \frac 1n \sum(X_i-\mu)^2\}\to_d N(0,Var((X_i-\mu)^2))$. (Variance doesn't have to be simplified).
- By the CLT: $\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}_n-\mu)\to _d N(0,\sigma^2)$. Delta method (using $g(x)=(x-\mu)^2$) results in $\sqrt n (\bar{X}_n-\mu)^2\to_d 0$.
- Now we have $\sqrt n (\frac {n-1}n S_n^2 - \sigma^2)\to_d N(0,Var((X_i-\mu)^2))$ (Slutsky, adding previous results together).
- I'm trying to find the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(S_n^2-\sigma^2)$, but I don't see how to get this from the previous bullet point. Can the delta method be applied using functions $g(x)$ that depend on $n$?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994221/proving-frac-sqrtns-n2-sigma2-sqrtu-2-sigma4-rightarrow-n0-1?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need delta method here.
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n^2-\sigma^2\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac1nS_n^2+\frac{n-1}n S_n^2 - \sigma^2 \right) = \frac{S_n^2}{\sqrt{n}} + \sqrt{n}\left(\frac {n-1}nS_n^2-\sigma^2\right).
$$
Since $S_n^2\xrightarrow{p}\sigma^2$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$, Slutsky's theorem implies the first summand tends to zero in distribution, and whence in probability. Again apply Slutsky's theorem and get the sum converges in distribution to $N(0,\text{Var}(X_1-\mu)^2)$.