# Prove convergence in distribution for i.i.d. normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables and each of them follows $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$ be the sample variance where $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is the sample mean.

1. Use the central limit theorem to show $\sqrt n(S^2-\sigma^2) \rightarrow N(0,\psi^2)$ in distribution. In addition, specify the expression for $\psi^2$.
2. Show that $\sqrt n log(S/\sigma) \rightarrow N(0,\tau^2)$ in distribution. 
   In addition, specify the expression for $\tau^2$

A little guidance and steps of work would be appreciated!

Comment: I edited the question. I think $\tau^2$ is the variance we want to get.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1994221/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512340/321264, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/434835/119261.